# Where can I see code for the C++ String function c_str

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I want to see the code of c_str function in c++.

How can I see that-->

(1) In Intel Compiler
(2) IN Visual Studio 2012 Compiler
(3) In GCC/MinGW.

Comment: @RedX - pardon me, but where can I see the sources? In the folder containing the IDEs? I am using C++ after a really long time, hence this seemingly silly question.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you need to see this?

Comment: @Borgleader I am just experimenting with C++ after a long time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `<string>` header file, and follow the trail of `#include`s until you find the `basic_string<T>` template. That's where the source of the `c_str` will be.

For example, in Visual Studio 2012 the function is located in the `<xstring>` header, and looks as follows:

```
const _Elem *c_str() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return pointer to null-terminated nonmutable array
    return (this->_Myptr());
    }
```

Comment: You mean `basic_string<T>`?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, absolutely. Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight kindly let me know in which folder I can see the headers including the <xstring> header? Thanks a lot....

Comment: @Arvind That would depend entirely on where you installed it... in VS you can right click the include directive to open the file in the context menu.

Comment: @Arvind it's under your `Program Files (x86)` folder, in the `Microsoft Visual Studio 11\VC\include`.

Answer (score 2):

With a decent ide, you can right click the function and the select "Go to Definition".
Visual studio has this option, so that will be the quickest for MSVC's implementation.
For gcc (libstdc++), I like using there [online doxygen docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/). [Here is a link to the implementation of c_str()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01006_source.html#l01800). For intel, I believe they use libstdc++ (gcc's implementation).

Answer (score 2):

With MinGW, you can find the header file at ...\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\debug\string.
The `c_str()` function is defined directly in that header, not in an include; I've placed the text below.

```
const _CharT* c_str() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    {
      const _CharT* __res = _Base::c_str();
      this->_M_invalidate_all();
      return __res;
    }
```

Comment: Which doesn't really help: `_Base::c_str()` is probably the interesting part.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Unless it too forwards to something else:-)  Obviously, you need the complete sources, and you need to follow the nested calls.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to find and open the include file where this
function is defined (supposing it is defined in an include
file—this is usually the case, but isn't required): what
I usually do when I want to see the definition of a class is
write a one line program which includes the appropriate header,
and nothing else.  Here:

```
#include <string>
```

(Yes, that's the complete program.)  I then compile with the `/E` option (VC++) or the `-E` option
(most other compilers), redirecting the output to a file, which
I can then peruse at my leisure.

This is easy to do directly from the command line, but if you
want to use VS, open up the properties on a source file which
includes `<string>`, go to the entry C/C++ -> Command Line, and
enter `/E` in the Additional Options pane.  Then compile.  The
output will appear in the output window; click on it, then
control-A followed by control-C, and you can paste it in
whatever editor you please.

Either way, once you've got the preprocessor output in an
editor, search from the top for `c_str` as a full word.

Answer (score 0):

If your on linux or using MinGW or WSL if you create  a file called string.txt
and put

```
#include <string>
```

and run `cpp string.txt > string.txt` from terminal or got to [this site](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/include/c++/7.2.1/string.html)